# How to share image using Branch-io by email in android

Tags: android, sharing, file-sharing, branch.io

I am using **Branch-io** to share content like Text, image(from URL), and Link.
I am all done and working perfect with **Facebook**, **Whatsapp**. I mean I am able to share Text and Link on **Gmail** also but unable to attach image.

This problem occurred only with **Gmail**.

**Here is my code:**

```
BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
                        .setCanonicalIdentifier("item/12345")
                        .setTitle(title)
                        .setContentDescription(message)
                        .setContentImageUrl(image)
                      //.setContentImageUrl(Uri.parse("file://"+downloadedImagePath).toString())
                        .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC);

                LinkProperties linkProperties = new LinkProperties()
                        .addControlParameter("$always_deeplink", "true")
                        .setFeature("sharing")
                        .setStage("1");
                String body = "Text Message";
                ShareSheetStyle shareSheetStyle = new ShareSheetStyle(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), body)
                        .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
                        .setSharingTitle("Share With");

                branchUniversalObject.showShareSheet((Activity) mContext,
                        linkProperties,
                        shareSheetStyle,
                        new Branch.BranchLinkShareListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onShareLinkDialogLaunched() {
                                LogUtils.v("Share Link", "Launched");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onShareLinkDialogDismissed() {
                                LogUtils.v("Share Link", "Dismissed");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLinkShareResponse(String sharedLink, String sharedChannel, BranchError error) {
                                LogUtils.v("Share Link", sharedLink);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChannelSelected(String channelName) {
                                LogUtils.v("Share Link", channelName);

                            }
                        });
            }
        }, false);
```

Let you know again, this code working perfect with Facebook, whatsapp but not with **Gmail(only issue not attaching image)**.

If anyone knows then please let me know what I'am doing wrong and what is the perfect way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this on our [test application](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/Branch-SDK-TestBed/src/io/branch/branchandroiddemo/MainActivity.java#L65), and everything works correctly when sharing with Gmail. Here's my test link: https://appsolutely.test-app.link/Mw2qFHRMxJ

Whenever you share a link via `showShareSheet()`, all the Branch Universal Object (BUO) information is attached to the link. If you keep sharing links for the same data, but across different channels, the only difference between the links for each channel will be `"~channel": "Gmail"`.

Looking at your code, I do not see any issues you could encounter with attaching the image URL, as you do call `.setContentImageUrl(image)` for the BUO object, so the issue may be in the way you are testing. After sharing your link via Gmail, I would suggest pasting it into the URL bar of your browser and attaching the following query parameter: `?debug=true`.

> E.g.: https://appsolutely.test-app.link/Mw2qFHRMxJ?debug=true

You could then view all of the data the link contains on the page that opens. If you see that the data contains the `"$og_image_url"` with the correct URL address, it means that the image was actually attached, as shown in the example below for my test link https://appsolutely.test-app.link/Mw2qFHRMxJ

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tested my sharedLink with debug enabled and can see `"$og_image_url":` there. But still image not attached on Gmail.

But I have done this using follwoing code: `shareLinkIntent_.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+imagePath)); // I first download the image then attached here`

This code can be found inside **ShareLinkManager**. And Now The problem is solved :)

Comment: I have this same issue. The image is shown in Facebook Messenger and WhatsApp but not in Gmail. I debugged it as suggested and the image_url is populated and correct. Has anybody at Branch addressed this yet or issued a suggestion for dealing with it?